# ANN to SNN Conversion Problem

Tags: ann

I am attempting an ANN to SNN conversion for an input dataset that is float32 and has a range of [-4, 4].
Training the ANN is straightforward, I used a small network of 7 input neurons, 7 hidden layer neurons and 20 output neurons (it is a classification problem). This ANN gave me an accuracy of ~95%.
For the ANN to SNN conversion I removed the bias from the ReLUs used in the ANN and retrained the ANN obtaining ~89% accuracy. In this case I am fine with the penatly in accuracy because this is my first time and I want to understand how the conversion works.

Next I imported the weights from the ANN to SNN, disabled the leakage of LIF neuron, disabled refractory period and set threshold to 0. The input I rate coded, eventhough this is nearly impossible for float32. (I am aware that I loose information with my input values to rate coded spike trains transformation)

**However:** I do not obtain the same results with the SNN as with the ANN. The values after the hidden layer are also different from the ANN after the hidden layer. So in the network itself I already get differences.

Could somebody help me out here? I am not sure why it is not working.
Is it the input to spike coding that messes up so much? Or am I using the wrong configurations?

Comment: Welcome! Could you please add the code you'd specifically like help with? That would help us better answer your question.